# Sorting a list of objects on 4 attributes, and then on random

Tags: python

I have the following problem. I want to solve a list with objects on 4 separate attributes, e.g. first it is sorted in descending order on attribute `a`, then on `b`, then attribute `c` and then attribute `d`. I do this like this:

```py
list = sorted(list, key=lambda x : (x.a, x.b, x.c, x.d), reverse=True)
```

But in case all attributes are still equal, I want to break the tie by determining their order at random. E.g. in an example problem:

```
1: a=3 b=2 c=3 d=1
2: a=3 b=2 c=3 d=1
3: a=3 b=2 c=3 d=1
4: a=1 b=3 c=4 d=5
5: a=1 b=3 c=4 d=5
6: a=0 b=1 c=1 d=1
7: a=0 b=1 c=1 d=1
```

I want the order of object 1, 2, and 3 to be determined randomly. Also the order of object 6 and 7 needs to be determined randomly. So object 1, 2 and 3 have 33% chance to come in one of the first three positions. Object 6 and 7 have a 50% chance to come in the sixth or seventh position.

If there are only ties between two objects this is easily solved:

```py
list = sorted(list, key=lambda x : (x.a, x.b, x.c, x.d, random.random()<0.5), reverse=True)
```

But what if 3 or more objects are tied? How would I make sure for instance that 3 equal objects have 33% to be first in their ordering.

I have been wondering this for a while now and I am curious if anyone has suggestions to efficiently solve this problem.

Comment: After sorting there is "itertools.groupby" to find groups which can then be shuffled randomly.

Comment: You can first shuffle the items in the list ``random.shuffle(list)`` and then sort based on the four columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would simply do this:

```
list = sorted(list, key=lambda x : (x.a, x.b, x.c, x.d, random.random()), reverse=True)
```

Since `random.random()` will generate a floating point number between 0 and 1, the odds of two records actually getting the same value here is vanishingly small. Elements that have the same attributes otherwise will get sorted by these random values.

If you *insist* on perfect randomness, you shouldn't use `random` to begin with, but something like this in a better random library would work:

```
options = list(range(len(xs)))
random.shuffle(options)
list = sorted(xs, key=lambda x : (x.a, x.b, x.c, x.d, options.pop(), reverse=True)
```

This works because the options are now guaranteed to be unique and assuming the random library does a perfect job of fairly shuffling the options, you will always get different values with an equal chance for all records.

Comment: If you're gonna shuffle a list of length `len(xs)`, you might as well just shuffle `xs` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understood the sorting function wrong. I ran a simulation and even using `random.random()<0.5` will still give 33% chance, but your suggestion is cleaner. Thank you.

Comment: @nocomment I think that's fair in many cases, although it may not be possible to shuffle the source - the idea remains the same of course.

Comment: Then you could make a copy, and shuffle and sort the copy in place.

Answer (score 1):

You could delete the `<0.5`.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that `sorted` is [stable](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts), you could just do

```
import random
import operator

random.shuffle(list_)
list_ = sorted(list_, key=operator.attrgetter('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), reverse=True)
# # in-place approach
# list_.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), reverse=True)
```

Comment: @dljve Note that I use `list_` instead of `list` since it is considered a bad practice to use reserved names as user-defined variables names. Cf. [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).